# Matplotlib load data using for cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to load 100 data files, every file has a name containing a progressive number: func_0.0.csv, func_0.1.csv, ..., func_9.9.csv

```
dati01={}
x1={}
y1={}
fig=pl.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)

for count in range(0,99):
nome_file = "func_%1.1f.csv" %(0.1*count)
dati01[count] = np.loadtxt(nome_file)
x1[count], y1[count]=dati01[count][:,0], dati01[count][:,1]
ax1.scatter(x1[count],y1[count], s=0.01, edgecolor=(count/1600., count/900, count/760.), label='')
```

the problem is that the interpreter gives me an error:

```
 line 56, in <module>
 dati01[count] = np.loadtxt(nome_file)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 848, in loadtxt
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 33.6033.682817
```

I cannot solve the problem, could anyone help me?

Comment: You have bad data in your files.  You'll either have to clean it up before matplotlib loads it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop keep track which file you are opening by printing out `nome_file`, or something like that. The last one that is opened before your program fails is the the file that has:

```
33.6033.682817
```

inside of it. This is not a valid float (there are no floating points with 2 decimal points). You need to correct the data in every file that has an issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to your problem, but you can also use `glob` and `re` packages for reading multiple files. Here is an example from my code:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import re

file_list=glob.glob('./BeamDistri*.dat')
file_list_length=len(file_list)    

number_regex=re.compile('_(\d+).')

for i in np.arange(file_list_length):
    file_beam=file_list[i]
    result_search=number_regex.search(file_beam).group(1)
    timestep=int(result_search)
    data_beam=np.genfromtxt(file_list[i])
    t=np.append(t, timestep*dt);


sorted_indices=np.argsort(t)
```